# Receiving an "Undefined index" notice when wanting to sum in a mysql query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to get the sum of a column from my database. When I try this code I get the error `Undefined index: sum(col_1)`. How can I do this? I'm a real beginner so keep it a bit simple.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_1";
$run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
    $col_ans[1] = $rows['sum(col_1)'];
        echo $col_ans[1];
    }
```

Comment: Tip: You can use `print_r($rows)` to see what the array indexes are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, and “Notice: Undefined offset”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/).

Comment: Tip: You may need to make sure to fields exist in the array before you are accessing them.

Ex. Can use ternary operator as below.
$x = isset($rows['col_1_sum']) ? $rows['col_1_sum'] : 'no-value'

Learn more about ternary operator https://www.codementor.io/@sayantinideb/ternary-operator-in-php-how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator-x0ubd3po6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't use the `SUM()` function inside your query, so you won't get any sum from the query

You can also try the following:

```php
$query =  "SELECT productName, SUM(productQty) AS 'Products Ordered'
FROM ctrlaproducttab
GROUP BY productName
";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    $productName = $row['productName'];
    $itemsOrdered = $row['Products Ordered'];
}
```

Notice that we're giving an alias name `Products Ordered` to the result of expression `SUM(productQty)`, and now we can use this alias name as an index in the associative array returned by `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily find sum of a column this way.

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(col_1) as col_1_sum FROM table_1";
$run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
echo $rows['col_1_sum'];
}
```